# Listen for changes to a computed property

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0

## The very simple setup

Lets say we have a computed property

```
data: {
 type: Array,
 computed: 'someFunc(someVar)'
}
```

and next we define `someFunc` as

```
function(someVar){
 return [
  'one string',
  'another string'
 ]
}
```

and include this in the DOM as

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="{{data}}" as="item">
 <paper-input value="{{item}}">
</template>
```

## The problem

How could I now *listen* for changes to the computed property, I notice that they **are** reflected back to the computed property, but an `observer` will not be fired. I also tried turning on `notify: true` and listening for a `data-changed` event with no luck and browsing through the Polymer API I can't seem to find a way to more directly listen for the correct events (though I know that `<paper-input>` is sending a notification, however I need my listener to be generic and not specific to `<paper-input>`)

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why this didn't work before, but I ran `bower update` and afterwards registering a listener like

```
listeners: {
    'data-changed': 'test'
},
```

suddenly did start working, so I guess I encountered some kind of bug or issue that has been fixed recently.

Answer (score -1):

This maybe will help you.

```
 <dom-module id="my-test">
      <template>
        <button on-tap="change">Change someVar value</button>
        <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{data}}" as="item">
           <paper-input value="{{item}}">
        </template>
      </template>

   <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'my-test',
      properties:{
        someVar:{
          type:Number,
          value:0
        },
        data: {
         type: Array,
         computed: 'someFunc(someVar)',//computed when someVar changes
         observer: "dataChanged"//fired when data changes
        }
      },
      ready: function() {

      },
      dataChanged: function(newValue, oldValue){
        console.log(newValue);//newValue of data
        console.log(oldValue);//old value of data
      },
      change: function(){
        this.someVar = this.someVar+1;
      },
      someFunc:function(someVar){
       return [
        'one string',
        'another string',
        this.someVar
       ]
      },
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

Comment: Of course directly changing the dependent variable will trigger the observer, however changing the `paper-input` will change the computed property, but not trigger the observer on the computed property.

Comment: I think that it's not possible to observe paths like " data.* " because data is an array and should be an object to it can use observer for an specific path. Array observation only can use for changes resulting from calls to push, pop, shift, unshift, and splice. When input changes it value, you are not doing nothing to the array,so the array does not call its observer